# .cts file - oracle database?

Tags: oracle

I have .cts file. It's posible that it's Oracle database file? If yes, how I can open it? This program make also pkb and pkn file.

Comment: Anything's possible, but it isn't a standard extension. .pkb might be a package body, but might not be Oracle either, and I don't recognise .pkn. Have you tried looking at it with a text editor? Is it binary? What platform is it on? How big is it? Where did you find it?

Comment: some info here http://filext.com/file-extension/CTS but may not be 100% true

Comment: I have program on Windows, it's like database, I need copy this database to excel. In program cataclog is file data.cts, 34 549 kb, it look so http://img585.imageshack.us/f/23284748.png/

Comment: So it's an internal database for some other application? If so it's unlikely to be Oracle, and you're unlikely to be able to get anything out of it unless your program has an export option. What is the program, something off-the-shelf or bespoke?

Answer (score 1):

http://filext.com/file-extension/CTS

this does not appear to be an oracle file